# Does Locust Keep Cookies between Containers?

Tags: python, locust

I'm running into an issue where the same requests of different headers and params is returning the same response. I think it might be my code structure:

```
def login(self):
    with self.client.get(...catch_response=True) as response:
def task(self):
    with self.client.get(...catch_response=True) as response:
```

Are cookies lost in between method call since the containers close after each method? If so, how would I go about keeping `catch_response` and data in between calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are cookies lost in between method call since the containers close after each method?

No, cookies should not be lost. Something else is going on. Maybe ”task”. Is being executed *before* login? Tasks are not strictly ordered (but you can use on_start instead). Try running in the debugger https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-in-debugger.html

Comment: I'm using a SequentialTaskSet so the order is set. I've also tried clearing cookies after each full user flow but the wrong response still shows up.

Comment: I tried printing the cookies, and it prints the first time but subsequent ones are empty {}.

Comment: Ok! Then I dont have any ideas..

Comment: Or maybe one thing: how are you printing your cookies? Can you show more of your locustfile?

Comment: I tried doing it inside of the container:
with self.client.get(...catch_response=True) as response:
     if response.ok:
          ...
          print(response.cookies.print_dict())

Comment: Ah. But are you sure all your endpoints will actually update cookies? Lack of cookies in the *response* doesnt really say anyhing about whether they were *sent*

Comment: Yes, I clean out the cookies after each call but I figured out the problem was with front end. Thanks for the help!